SQL difference function not working with Hebrew text
I have a SQL table with some Hebrew and English columns and I want to search using difference() function to return the records that are the most similar to the search query which can be in Hebrew or English.
The issue is that it only works with the English values, but for the Hebrew values difference() always returns 4.
Example I have a table of countries with a column of English names and a column for Hebrew names.
Table and sample data:
create table dbo.Country(
    CountryId int not null identity primary key,
    CountryEN nvarchar(50) not null 
        constraint ck_Country_CountryEN_cannot_be_blank check(CountryEN > '')
        constraint u_Country_CountryEN unique,
    CountryHE nvarchar(50) COLLATE Hebrew_CI_AS_KS_WS not null 
        constraint ck_Country_CountryHE_cannot_be_blank check(CountryHE > '')
        constraint u_Country_CountryHE unique
)

insert Country(CountryEN, CountryHE)
select 'Hungary', N'אונגארן'
union select 'Czech Republic', N'טשעכיי'
union select 'Poland', N'פוילן'

My sproc:
create or alter procedure dbo.CountryGet(
    @CountryId int = 0,
    @CountryName nvarchar(50) = '',
    @All bit = 0,
    @Message varchar(500) = '' output
)
as
begin
    declare @return int = 0
    
    select co.CountryId, co.CountryEN, co.CountryHE
    from Country co
    where co.CountryId = @CountryId
    or difference(co.CountryEN,@CountryName) >= 4
    or difference(co.CountryHE,@CountryName) >= 4
    or @All = 1

    return @return
end

Testing with wrong spelling of country:
exec CountryGet @CountryName = 'Hunger'

Returns one row as expected



CountryId
CountryEN
CountryHE




2
Hungary
אונגארן



Testing with Hebrew value with no spelling mistakes:
exec CountryGet @CountryName = N'אונגארן'

Returns all rows



CountryId
CountryEN
CountryHE




1
Czech Republic
טשעכיי


2
Hungary
אונגארן


3
Poland
פוילן



fiddle
When I use or co.CountryHE = @CountryName instead of difference(), I get the value as expected. But I do want to include similar results.

The DIFFERENCE() documentation states that it is based on comparing SOUNDEX() results, but the SOUNDEX() documentation states that it is "based on how the string sounds when spoken in English."  A quick test of SOUNDEX() shows that it returns all zeros for each of the Hebrew strings. See this db<>fiddle. It appears that non-English is just not supported.

Is there any other approach I can take? I believe I'm not the first one with this issue.

This just sucks to do in sql. Some people implement the levenstein distance and try to make it work, others give up and move the logic into elasticsearch. Some even quit programming and become farmers

I dropped in text from several other languages and got similar results. You might need to add a new column containing a character-by-character phonetic translation of the Hebrew names to the English alphabet to be able to use SOUNDEX() and DIFFERENCE(). fiddle. The same would need to be done for the search terms. I do not know offhand of an existing phonetic substitution function that would perform this task, so you may need to write your own - "בּ" -> "b", "ב" -> "v", "גּ" -> "g", etc.  Vowels can be dropped, since they are ignore by SOUNDEX().

@siggemannen - Farming nowadays can be highly technical. Not sure if the average programmer is up to the challenge.

Just a nitpicking side node: This isn't Hebrew, it's Yiddish. A language that's written in Hebrew letters but it's more a mix between Hebrew and German.
As for the question itself, I've never heard of any soundex/difference method implementation for Yiddish, in T-SQL or any other language, for that matter. You might need to implement this yourself or neglect the idea.

@ZoharPeled I know it's Yiddish but the question is for Hebrew letters not for Hebrew language.

I'm sure you do, Shmiel is a very Yiddish name - however since Difference() is based on SoundEx(), that's a point worth mentioning - since Yiddish and Hebrew sounds very different.
